# Solving $6ab+a+b-36pq-19p-13q=7$ where $a,b,p,q \in \mathbb{N}$, $a,b,p,q \neq 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there an efficient way to find solutions to the equation:

$6ab+a+b-36pq-19p-13q=7$ where $a,b,p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,b,p,q \neq 0$

If the equation has no solutions, how could you prove that, that is the case?

Edit: The equation can in fact be expressed in the form;

$\frac{(6a+1)(6b+1)}{6}- \frac{1}{6}  - \frac{(36p+13)(36q+19)}{36} - \frac{247}{36} =7$

which is the same as

$6(6a+1)(6b+1)-(36p+13)(36q+19)=11$

but I  am still left wondering how to move forwards.

Comment: No I shall clarify that thanks.

Comment: You should have $\frac{(6a+1)(6b+1)}{6}-\frac{1}{6} - \frac{(36p+13)(36q+19)}{36} +\frac{247}{36}=7$ and $6(6a+1)(6b+1)-(36p+13)(36q+19)=11$

Comment: The solutions do not seem to be satisfying that equation, are you sure that is correct?

Comment: $6*(6*5+1)*(6*7+1)-(36*1+13)*(36*4+19) = 6*31*43 - 49*163 = 7998 - 7987 =11$

Comment: I did not see the 11 in the original equation. Sorry, I will edit right away.

Comment: No problems. Note $(36p+13)(36q+19)+11 \equiv 6 \mod 36$ and so $\frac{(36p+13)(36q+19)+11}{6} \equiv 1 \mod 6$. The question is then which $\frac{(36p+13)(36q+19)+11}{6}$ have factors $\equiv 1 \mod 6$. Not sure where you'd go from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$(6a+1)(6b+1)=6(6ab+a+b)+1$$ and $$(36p+13)(36q+19)=36(36pq+19p+13q)+247$$ Multiply your equation by $36$ and use these formulas to rewrite it as something like $xy-zw=n$ for some number $n$.

Comment: Ok I shall try that

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

You can factor:

$$\frac{1}{6} (6a + 1)(6b + 1) = 36(p + \frac{13}{36})(q + \frac{19}{36}) + \frac{11}{36}$$

$$6(6a+1)(6b+1) = (36p + 13)(36q + 19) + 11$$

Note that $RHS \equiv LHS \equiv 6 \pmod {36}$. Some trial and error with $p, q$ yields $(5, 7, 1, 4), (2, 32, 1, 8), (3, 27, 1, 10), (9, 11, 1, 12)$. With $p = 2$, the first solution is $(15, 5, 2, 5)$. Solutions certainly exist.

Comment: Should be (15,5,2,5) I think.

Comment: You are correct. Edited

Answer (score 2):

It has at least the solutions $(7,5,1,4)$ and $(5,7,1,4)$.

Comment: Was there an insight into the equation that allowed you to find these or was that by trial and error?

Comment: Since you only want positive solutions, I rearranged your equation so that all of the terms were positive. Then I chose some small values for $p$ and $q$ and proceeded based on the constraints.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

equation:

$6ab+a+b-36xy-19x-13y=7$

Reshniya have the form:

$a=3(12k-q-p)(q+p-2)+19k-q-p-1$

$b=6q+6p-7$

$x=3(12k-q-p)(q+p-2)+31k-2q-2p-1$

$y=q+p-2$

more:

$a=2q(18k-3q+8)+19k+10$

$b=6q+4$

$x=3q(12k-2q+5)+25k+13$

$y=q$

more:

$a=3q(12k+q-6)+19k+q-10$

$b=6q+1$

$x=3q(12k+q-6)+7k-4$

$y=q$

$q,p,k$ - Asked us integers.